# Hide options in a select list using mixitup.js and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mixitup

I'm using mixitup.js to filter cities by country. I want to hide and show cities by the selected country.

Filtering works fine, but is there some way to show only cities that are included in certain country? This is what I'm working on:  [Codepen](http://bit.ly/1Hs6pf7)

I found this [Fiddle](http://bit.ly/1EUWAQ2) but I don't know how to use it if I have more than two select boxes. 
E.g. `Country > City > Province`

Comment: you're saying that the cities dropdown should show only the cities of the selected country ?

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$('#country').change(function(){ // when you change a country
  var country = $(this).val(); // example: .usa OR .france OR .sweden
  $('#city > option').show(); // show all the cities
  if(country){ // if the value is not ""
    $('#city > option[data-country!="'+country+'"]').hide(); // hide the cities of other countries
  }
});
```

For this to work you need to add a reference of country name in the city dropdown, like this

```
<select id="country">
  <option value="">Country</option>
  <option value=".usa">USA</option>
  <option value=".sweden">Sweden</option>
  <option value=".france">France</option>
</select>

<select id="city">
  <option value="" data-country=".">City</option>
  <option value=".la" data-country=".usa">LA</option>
  <option value=".ny" data-country=".usa">NY</option>
  <option value=".stockholm" data-country=".sweden">Stockholm</option>
  <option value=".gothenburg" data-country=".sweden">Gothenburg</option>
  <option value=".paris" data-country=".france">Paris</option>
  <option value=".cannes" data-country=".france">Cannes</option>
</select>
```

Here is a demo **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbEYLb**

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Dhiraj's implementation, I created a hierarchical 3-category filter: http://codepen.io/tuomastik/pen/PPLXwa. I hope somebody will find it useful! :)

Hierarchical structure:

```
<select id="project">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value=".project-1">Project 1</option>
  <option value=".project-2">Project 2</option>
</select>

<select id="dataset">
  <option value="" parent-value=".">All</option>
  <option value=".dataset-a" parent-value=".project-1">Dataset a</option>
  <option value=".dataset-b" parent-value=".project-2">Dataset b</option>
  <option value=".dataset-c" parent-value=".project-2">Dataset c</option>
</select>

<select id="visualization">
  <option value="" parent-value=".">All</option>
  <option value=".visualization-I" parent-value=".dataset-a">Visualization I</option>
  <option value=".visualization-II" parent-value=".dataset-b">Visualization II</option>
  <option value=".visualization-III" parent-value=".dataset-b">Visualization III</option>
  <option value=".visualization-IV" parent-value=".dataset-c">Visualization IV</option>
  <option value=".visualization-V" parent-value=".dataset-c">Visualization V</option>
  <option value=".visualization-VI" parent-value=".dataset-c">Visualization VI</option>
</select>
```